# SQL Query - What is the sql code to find the time intervals of my customers' visits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I'm tasked to perform this!
I want to find the number of days before my customers re-visit my hotel using sql query.

This is my current data table:

```
Passport No. Customer Name Check-in Date Check-out Date
123456       David         1/3/2011      5/3/2011
123456       David         8/3/2011      11/3/2011
654321       John          11/3/2011     18/3/2011
987654       Michael       11/3/2011     18/3/2011
654321       John          20/3/2011     24/3/2011
123456       David         7/7/2011      9/7/2011
987654       Michael       5/5/2011      8/5/2011
654321       John          20/4/2011     25/4/2011
123456       David         11/8/2011     18/8/2011
987654       Michael       1/6/2011      5/6/2011
567891       Mary          7/9/2011      3/10/2011
```

Comment: So what's your question? Did you try anything, yet?

Comment: Date difference between check-out Date (first record) - Check-in Date (next record) right?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (mysql,mssql,oracle)?

Comment: im using MS SQL. yes, the difference between the first record and the next record!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `RANK` within a CTE to offset the previous record with the next record in order to compare the next check in date with the previous check out date:

```
WITH RankedVisits ([Rank], PassportNo, CustomerName, CheckInDate, CheckOutDate) AS
(
    SELECT 
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PassportNo, CheckInDate) AS [Rank],
            CustomerName,
            PassportNo,
            CheckInDate,
            CheckOutDate,
    FROM 
            Visits
)

SELECT 
        NextVisit.CustomerName, 
        DATEDIFF(D, PreviousVisit.CheckOutDate, NextVisit.CheckInDate) AS DaysBetween
FROM 
        RankedVisits AS PreviousVisit
JOIN    RankedVisits AS NextVisit
            ON PreviousVisit.[Rank] = NextVisit.[Rank] - 1  --Offset record with previous record

WHERE   NextVisit.PassportNo = PreviousVisit.PassportNo
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012, there are `LEAD` and `LAG` functions that will make my example above a lot cleaner (and faster).